# Django Authenticate method not working on custom Model

Tags: python, django

I am trying the build in method authenticate() to login employees but that does not seem to work. I have not used the default model User provided by django instead I have used my own model Employee here.

Here is what I have in my views.py

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        password = request.POST['password']
        emailid = request.POST['email']

        employee = auth.authenticate(username=emailid,password=password)

        if employee is not None:
            auth.login(request,employee)
            return render(request,'register/html')
        
            
                
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Email id dosent exist')
            return redirect('login')
            
    else:
        return render(request,'employee/login.html')
```

while my custom code does the authentication

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        password = request.POST['password']
        emailid = request.POST['username']

         if Employee.objects.filter(firstname=emailid).exists():
            if Employee.objects.filter(password=password):
                messages.success(request,'Loged Out')
                return redirect('vacant-rooms')
            else:
                messages.error(request,'Wrong emailid')
                return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'wrong password')
            return redirect('login')
     else:
        return render(request,'employee/login.html')
```

Here is my model

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    phoneno = models.IntegerField()
    emailid = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    salary = models.IntegerField()
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    aadharno = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    datejoined = models.DateField(default=timezone)
```

Its a dumb question maybe but is the buit in authentication not working because I do not have a username field in my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't do that. Django already has a User infrastructure and to use functions like authenticate, you need to inherit one of the AbstractUser or AbstractBaseUser classes. If you just define models like that, you have to do a lot of the work that Django has already done, and I definitely don't recommend it. I leave some helpful documentation and articles below. If you need any help, write a comment and I can help as best I can.

[Official Django Doc Customizing authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/)

[Custom User Model](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/)

[How to Extend User Model](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html)