# My Django Password encryption is not working

Tags: python, django, django-views, bcrypt

I have a User table that has some attributes where the Password is being stored as a String. I am trying to store it as an encrypted string using bcrypt, but for some reason it is not changing and the password continues to be the one before encryption.

I have this in my settings.py:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So2Bh.png)

And the method to add my User to the table is in views.py as this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHE63.png)
What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please do not use images of your code. Instead edit the question and add it as text (copy-paste) and format it as code (select and press curly braces in editor or ctrl+k)

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't do custom encryption. Django already has an encryption system. You can easily integrate bcrpyt as in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/passwords/#pbkdf2-and-bcrypt). Then all you have to do is;

```
passwd = user_data['passwd']
user = user_serializer.save()
user.set_password(passwd)
user.save()
```

EDIT:

[Changing password Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#changing-passwords)

Comment: So, even if my 'Password' attribute in the User class is a CharField, it will store the encrypted password?

Comment: If you do not use the user model by inheriting or extending Django's base user models, I think you should not do this. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65025584/django-authenticate-method-not-working-on-custom-model/65028791#65028791), I explained why and how to do it. If you defined it this way, you shouldn't need to define the password field because it is already defined in base models.

Answer (score 0):

this is not the why you should create users with API
first install django rest framework (DRF)

then do this

serializers.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers



class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializes a user object"""

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('__all__')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {
                'write_only': True,
                'style': {'input_type': 'password'}
            }
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create and return new user"""

        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user
```

permissions.py

```
from rest_framework import permissions


    class UpdateOwnUser(permissions.BasePermission):
    """Allow user to just change their own profile"""

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        """Check if user is trying to change their own profile"""

        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        return obj.id == request.user.id
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework import viewsets
from . import permissions, serializers

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Handle creating and updating profiles"""

    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.UpdateOwnUser,)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from . import views

router = DefaultRouter()

router.register('profile', views.UserProfileViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

in the root url.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('profiles_api.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your django configurations are wrong, they should be these:

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
]
```